# Correct way to continue spring batch job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job with set of steps.

If some step was failed due to exception or was stopped, I have 2 possible ways to restart it:

1) JobOperator.restartJob(long executionId) - restart by exectution id

2) Read failed JobExecution from database and call Job.execute(JobExecution execution)

First way will create a copy of JobExecution and run it using method Job.execute(JobExecution execution). This way doesn't 
rerun already completed steps if they have restartable property "false". This is desirable behaviour for me but problem with this way
is that I have large copy of execution context and it is not so fast to deserialize it.

Second way will just rerun existing JobExecution instance. Also, it will rerun all completed steps even if they have restartable
property "false". This confuses me because I just want to continue task execution for not completed steps.

Can you please explain me what way should I use?

Comment: Why do you have a large `ExecutionContext`?

Comment: In `ExecutionContext` I store all required data for the job. In this case more than 11 million of longs, it allows me to resume job without rereading ids from DB.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that.  The `ExecutionContext` isn't a cache.  That's the reason you're having issues with number 1 in the first place.

Comment: I have a follow steps:  
1. step that read 'List' of ids into 'ExecutionContext'  
2. step that get 'List' of ids from 'ExecutionContext' (Reader) and read it sequentially.

3. step that processed ids and then write processed data


On fail on second or thirt step `ExecutionContext` will store in DB.
On restarting job from `ExecutionContext` will be restored ids that was not processed.

Comment: That architecture is flawed.  You really should be using a driving query for that.  You can read about it in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders